# casperJS evaluate and jquery methods

Tags: jquery, casperjs

I'm new to casperjs and I'm having an issue with the evaluate() function.

the HTML code (which i cannot change right now)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>some other field</td>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>125.3</td>
    <td>some other value</td>
    <td>something else</td>
</table>
```

The goal is to start scraping info from these tables, getting the first td for each row, and later doing something with them.  The problem I'm having is that the "each" function isn't doing anything.

I tried it also just returning the tr to a variable and doing a $.each() on it, but it also doesn't work.  Is each() not made available in evaluate?  (I was under the impression that in evaluate you had most of the jQuery methods)

```
var evaluatedItems = this.evaluate(function() {
        var items = [];        
        $("td").filter(function() { return $.text([this]) == 'Price'; }).closest('table').find('tr').each(function() {
            var col = $(this).find('td:first');
            require('utils').dump(col);
            items.push(col);
        });
        return items;
    });
```

Comment: This only works if jQuery is loaded inside the DOM context.

Comment: How do I do that?  Thanks.  (If you post an answer, I can mark it as answered)   EDIT:  I found this on their site: casper.page.injectJs('/path/to/jquery.js'); is this what you're suggesting?

Comment: I tried it, and it still didn't work.... Does anyone have any suggestions, using my function (this.evaluate(function() {...

Comment: Actually got it working now.  If you create an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer to this question along with your code snippet that solved your problem. It's ok to accept your own answers.

Comment: done.  i figured since i hadn't really figured it out on my own, but it was mike who pointed me in the correct place, i wanted to give him the opinion of creating an answer so i could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments, I realized that what I was doing was putting in the URL of the jQuery library which wasn't allowed.

Once I put in the actual directory location, it worked. It was easier to put it in the instantiation of casper.

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'error',    
    clientScripts: ["<location of directory containing jquery>/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"]
});
```

but the other option is using:

```
 page.casperInsertJs("<location of directory containing jquery>/jquery-1.7.2.min.js");
```